# Why ls -1 | xargs -I{} echo -n {}{}{} does not print in right order?

Tags: bash, printing, xargs, ls

```
Ubuntu$ ls -1
```

file1 file2

```
Ubuntu$ ls -1 | xargs -I{} echo -n {}{}{}
```

file1file1file1file2file2file2

Why don't I get the result in this order?:  file1file2file1file2file1fil2

Comment: If you provide more information, you might get more specific answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `xargs` executes the command (`echo`) for each word in its input. And of course `{}` is the same each time. Even if you repeat it many times.

You can do what you want using `for`:

```
ls=$(ls -1)
for i in {1..3}
do
  echo $ls
done
```

Example of usage:

```
$ mkdir d ; cd d
<d>$ touch file1 file2 file3
<d>$ ls=$(ls -1)
<d>$ for i in {1..3}
> do
>   echo $ls
> done
file1 file2 file3
file1 file2 file3
file1 file2 file3
```